# Impresión de credencial por ambos lados **C#**

Tags: c#

Hola que tal buenas tardes, estoy desarrollando un sistema para generar credenciales vehicular, pero estoy teniendo un problema, al momento de mandar a imprimir me **imprime solo por un solo lado (cara)**, lo que quiero hacer es que me tome la misma credencial para imprimir del otro lado el demás contenido, el desarrollo lo estoy haciendo en **C#**, si alguien ya a trabajado con esto o sabe de como configurar está parte en el código les agradecería mucho su ayuda, de antemano muchas gracias.

**Este es el código que estoy utilizando para mandar a imprimir.**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using KeepAutomation.Barcode.Crystal;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.WinForms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
namespace credenciales_v1.controllers
{
    class crear_credencial
    {

```
    public static void crear(int id)
    {

        using (var cnn = new data.db_conn())
        {
            try
            {
                //string ruta_foto = @"C:\credenciales\fotos\";
                //string ruta_QR = @"C:\credenciales\QR\";
                var printCont = (from _print in cnn.sys_print select _print);
                if (printCont.Count() > 0) {
                var prints = (from _print in cnn.sys_print select _print).FirstOrDefault();
                var sql = (from _lic in cnn.vst_credencial select _lic).FirstOrDefault();


                    PrintDocument _licencia = new PrintDocument();
                    PrinterSettings set = new PrinterSettings();
                    _licencia.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = prints.impresora;
                    set.Duplex= Duplex.Vertical;
                    _licencia.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(crear_imaen);
                    _licencia.Print();



                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
    public static void crear_imaen(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        using (var cnn = new data.db_conn())
        {
            if (ev.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.IsValid && ev.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.CanDuplex)
                ev.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.Duplex = System.Drawing.Printing.Duplex.Vertical;
            Bitmap m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(516, 324);
            PointF point = new PointF(0, 0);
            SizeF maxSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF(516, 324);
            HtmlRender.Render(Graphics.FromImage(m_Bitmap),
                                                   "<html><img src=C:/credenciales/caras_credenciales_1.png ><html>",
                                                    point, maxSize);

            /*HtmlRender.Render(Graphics.FromImage(m_Bitmap),
                                                    "<html><img src=C:/credenciales/lic_2.jpg ><html>",
                                                     point, maxSize);*/

            var sql = (from _lic in cnn.vst_credencial select _lic).FirstOrDefault();

            Graphics writter = Graphics.FromImage(m_Bitmap);


            /*String 
                text1 = "", 
                str = sql.emergencias;

            char[] array = str.ToCharArray();
            int ctn_pal = 0;

            for (int a = 0; a < str.Length; a++){
                if (ctn_pal < 21){
                    char letter = array[a];
                    text1 += letter;
                    ctn_pal++;
                }else{
                    text1 += Environment.NewLine;
                    ctn_pal = 0;
                }
            }*/

            //writter.DrawString(text1, new Font("Arial", 10, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 165, 30);
            //writter.DrawString(text1, new Font("Arial", 10, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 165, 30);

            m_Bitmap.Save(@"C:\credenciales\1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(m_Bitmap, 0, 0);

        }
    }

}
```

}

**Credencial:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-----*

> Estoy utilizando una impresora para imprimir credenciales, (plástico).

*

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código mostrando como estas imprimiendo ahora, sino, veo difícil que alguien te ayude

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.duplex?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Gracias ya le edite, buen día.